# how can i delete a collection with special attribute

Tags: mongodb, meteor, database

i want to delete some of my subs collections where topic as a special value but i dont know how.

```js
  deleteThisTopic() {
    Topics.remove(this.props.topic._id);
    Subs.remove({"topic":"this.props.topic"});
  }

  test() {
    window.topicText=this.props.topic.text;
  }
  render() {
    return (

      <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <Link to="/sub"><li onClick={this.test.bind(this)}>{this.props.topic.text}  ARN:  {this.props.topic.arn}</li></Link>
        <Link to="/log"><button onClick={this.test.bind(this)}>S'inscrire</button></Link>
        <Link to="/"><button >Cacher</button></Link>
        <button onClick={this.deleteThisTopic.bind(this)}>Suprimer</button>
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just pass the `topic` *value*:

```
deleteThisTopic() {
  const topic = this.props.topic._id;
  Topics.remove(topic);
  Subs.remove({ topic }); // equals to { topic: topic }
}
```